# Using ninject as a WPF view mode locator - viewmodels as singletons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject, viewmodellocator

I'm using ninject's kernel as a viewmodel locator in a WPF application.

The kernel helper class:

```
public static class IoCKernel
    {
        private static IKernel kernel;

        public static void Init(params NinjectModule[] modules)
        {
            if (kernel == null)
            {
                kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
            }
        }

        public static T Get<T>()
        {
            return kernel.Get<T>();
        }
    }
```

And the `ViewModelLocator` exposes the `Get` method like:

```
public class ViewModelLocator : IViewModelLocator
    {    
        public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return IoCKernel.Get<MainWindowViewModel>();
            }
        }
    }
```

And when the instance is needed, it's called like:

```
IoCKernel.Get<IViewModelLocator>().MainWindowViewModel;
```

However, the `IoCKernel.Get<MainWindowViewModel>()` will always return a new instance. Is there a way to make it only work with one instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up a binding in Ninject, you can call the `InSingletonScope` method:

```
Bind<IYourInterface>().To<YourClass>().InSingletonScope();
```

In your case (you do not have an interface for the view model) it might be:

```
Bind<MainWindowViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

See here for more info : [Object Scopes in Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

Comment: One minor improvement I would suggest to the original code: he's using a static class as a wrapper for the kernel. If you change this to a regular class that implements an interface then you can bind that interface to the implementation using InSingletonScope and have the injector inject itself into the classes that need it.